# How to set editButtonItem title in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I know it's easy in Swift 2.2. Like this:

```
editButtonItem().title = "My Title"
```

But in Swift 3, `editButtonItem` becomes a property of `UIViewController`. And `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have title any more. So this doesn't work:

```
editButtonItem.title = "My Title" // doesn't work
```

Please help me with this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. This may help you!

   ```
   let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
   navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

   let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
   navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
   ```